# query bad performance

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan

Is there anything I can do to improve this query performance? I have included the  execution plan and the Server Profiler output. Is there a index that can help? I see there is a Index Seek that is taking some time can I do anything to help that? in the Server profile I see the reads looks high is can there be something to help that?

```
SELECT dbo.Templates.VersionKey
FROM            dbo.Templates INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Indications ON dbo.Templates.Id = dbo.Indications.TemplateId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sentences ON dbo.Indications.SentenceId = dbo.Sentences.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SentenceParts ON dbo.Sentences.Id = dbo.SentenceParts.SentenceId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SentencePartValues ON dbo.SentenceParts.Id = dbo.SentencePartValues.SentencePartId
WHERE        (dbo.Templates.Status <> 8) AND 
(dbo.Templates.IsCurrentVersion = 1) AND 
(dbo.Indications.IsActive = 1) AND 
(dbo.Indications.IsCurrentVersion = 1)  
AND (NOT (Sentences.[IsDeleted] = 1)) 
AND (NOT (SentenceParts.[IsDeleted] = 1)) 
AND (NOT (SentencePartValues.[IsDeleted] = 1)) 
and
(SUBSTRING(dbo.SentencePartValues.LiteralValue, 12, 36) = 'a2278339-8add-ff3d-8baa-9654b8b8d00b')
```

execution plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By68aKtfp

SQL Server Profiler
[image]

Comment: `AND (NOT (Sentences.[IsDeleted] = 1))` etc might be better as `AND Sentences.[IsDeleted] = 0` to avoid an inequality predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### yes

Don't use substring in your where clause:

[image: NUTS]

All of the time in this query is spent seeking through 25,219,726 rows in `SentencePartValues`, then applying the filter/substring to `LiteralValue`.

Of course, it's easy to say that, but it doesn't do you much good in practice.

It may be easier for you to do a double-wildcard `LIKE` search, but if `LiteralValue` is an n/varchar(max), or sql_variant, then you're screwed either way.

- [Max Data Type Columns And Predicates Aren’t SARGable](https://erikdarling.com/sargability-week-max-data-type-columns-and-predicates-arent-sargable/)

You may need to add a computed column to the table and then index it appropriately for your query.

`ALTER TABLE dbo.SentencePartValues ADD LV_substring AS TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(dbo.LiteralValue, 12, 36) AS uniqueidentifier);`

or

`ALTER TABLE dbo.SentencePartValues ADD LV_substring AS TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(dbo.LiteralValue, 12, 36) AS varchar(36));`

The `TRY_CAST` to uniqueidentifier may fail if certain values end up in the substring that can't be converted.

Adding the column without the `PERSISTED` keyword will prevent a long blocking operation from occurring while you add the column. Of course, like I said, you'll need to index it for it to be useful in general.

```
CREATE INDEX 
    whatever 
ON dbo.SentencePartValues
    (LV_substring, SentencePartId)
INCLUDE
    (IsDeleted) 
WHERE 
    IsDeleted = 1
WITH
    (ONLINE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON);
```

You can use `ONLINE = ON` if you're on Enterprise Edition, otherwise you'll have to omit it and suffer.

Comment: Would a join on a SUBSTRING be better ?

Comment: @Jefferson absolutely not.